# Let G be a group containing an element of order 5 and an element of order 7. Explain why G must have at least 35 elements.

Tags: group-theory

First, note by Lagrange's theorem that every element must have order 1, 5, 7, or 35.

If there is an element of order 35 then the group is cyclic, so there is some  with order 35. Then 5 has order 7, and 7 has order 5.

Now suppose there is no element of order 35. Only the identity has order 1, so every non-identity element must have order 5 or order 7.

If there is no element with order 7, then every non-identity element has order 5. Therefore  is the union of  subgroups of order 5. Since 5 is prime, each pair of subgroups intersects trivially, which means that we must have ||=35=4+1, but there is no integer  satisfying this equation.

Similarly, if there is no element with order 5, then every non-identity element has order 7. Then  is the union of  subgroups of order 7. Since 7 is prime, again the subgroups intersect trivially, so ||=35=6+1. Again, there is no integer  satisfying this equation.

We conclude that  must contain at least one element of order 5 and at least one element of order 7.

Is this the correct approach

Comment: Your first sentence using Lagrange's Theorem is not right. The group might be say the set of permutations of an eight element set, with order $8!=40320,$ which has elements of orders 2 through 8 along with many more orders.

Comment: It actually seems you proved a different result: If $|G|=35$ then $G$ contains an element with order $5$ and an element with order $7$. But the title question wants a proof that if $G$ contains an element with order $5$ and an element with order $7$, then $|G| \geq 35$.

Answer (score 2):

$G$ : finite group.

$|a| $ divides $|G|$.

$|a|=5 \implies |G|=5k' $ for some positive integer $k'$.

Again, $|b|=7 \implies |G|=7k'' $ for some positive integer $k''$.

$Gcd(5, 7) =1$

Hence, $|G|= 7\cdot 5 k  $ for some $k\in \Bbb{N}$